# NullPointerException in Actionlistener with sql statement

Tags: java, sql, user-interface, actionlistener

im having problem with getting back password from sql statement, when im trying to make it in a simple class it works for me perfectly im getting result back but when im trying to use this in GUI actionlistener im getting NullPointerException. There is my part of a code, i hope you will be able to find out solution for this problem.

Code:

```
package GUI;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import main.Controll;
import utility.DBController;

public class Main extends JFrame {

private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
private JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
private JButton login = new JButton("Login");
private JLabel loginLabel = new JLabel("Username: ");
private JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password: ");
private JLabel test = new JLabel();
private JPasswordField passwordText = new JPasswordField(8);
private JTextField loginText = new JTextField(8);
private ImageIcon logo = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Logo.jpg"));
private JLabel Logo = new JLabel(logo);
private DBController db;
private Controll con;
private String temp;
private String usr;
private String pwd;


public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IndexOutOfBoundsException, NullPointerException, SQLException
{
    Main main = new Main();
}

public Main() throws ClassNotFoundException, IndexOutOfBoundsException, NullPointerException, SQLException
{
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setTitle("Login");
    frame.setSize(600,400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.add(Logo);
    frame.add(login);

    frame.add(loginText);
    frame.add(passwordText);
    frame.add(loginLabel);
    frame.add(passwordLabel);
    frame.add(test);



    login.setBounds(250, 180, 100, 30); //login button
    login.addActionListener(new LoginListener());


    loginText.setBounds(250, 100, 120, 20);
    passwordText.setBounds(250, 135, 120, 20);
    loginLabel.setBounds(180, 100, 100, 15);
    passwordLabel.setBounds(180, 135, 100, 15);

    Logo.setBounds(450, 0, 150, 68);




}

private class LoginListener  implements ActionListener
{

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
          usr = loginText.getText();
          pwd = passwordText.getText();
          try {
            temp = db.login(loginText.getText());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IndexOutOfBoundsException
                | NullPointerException | SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
          if(temp == pwd)
          {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success");
          }
          else
          {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fail");
          }









      }
}

}
```

Code of my sql statement:

```
    public String login(String username) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IndexOutOfBoundsException, NullPointerException
{
    DBConnection db = new DBConnection("sdj");
    ArrayList<Object[]> result;
    result = db.query("SELECT password FROM `users` WHERE username = ?", username);
    Object[] temp;
    String incorrect = "incorrect";
    try
    {
    temp = result.get(0);
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException exception)
    {
        return incorrect;
    }
    String usr = (String) temp[0];
    return usr;
}
```

And finally im getting error like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at GUI.Main$LoginListener.actionPerformed(Main.java:90)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You don't initialise the variable `private DBController db` anywhere in your code. Then in your `actionPerformed()` method you attempt to call the login method on this null variable:

```
temp = db.login(loginText.getText());
```

You may be mixing this up with the db you declare in the login method, which is different.